# how to only allow access to website if user access through a certain website in IIS

Tags: iis, ip, filtering

How can I deny access for everyone except users that originally access the site from a specific website? I use IIS 10. Does really IP/Domain filtering in IIS works for this? I tried to simulate this by setting up 2 web applications in IIS, in web app 1 I only allow access from localhost, in web app 2 I created a link to web app 1. I then opened web app 2 from my client and clicked the link that takes me to web app 1. But then I am not allowed to access. The only way I can access is if I add my own client IP in the allowed IP list.